# Update a lookup field in scheduled apex class

Tags: apex, class, scheduled-apex, update

I am trying to update the `BMCServiceDesk__Status_ID__c` (lookup field) on the `BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c` object with a status of Closed.

I need to get all BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c records with a status of `BMCServiceDesk__Status_ID__c` = 'Resolved' that have been in such state for longer than 30 days.

**I don't understand how I'm supposed to be able to update the `BMCServiceDesk__Status_ID__c`field with a status of closed as i'm getting the**

> error message "Field is not writeable:
>   BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c.BMCServiceDesk__Status_ID__c

Many `BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c' records can be related to one`BMCServiceDesk__Status__c` record.

```
global class Set_Status_Closed_Scheduled Implements Schedulable // If an Incident has in a static Resolved state for 30 days, change it to Closed

{
global void execute (SchedulableContext sc)
{
    changeStatusToClosed();
}
public void changeStatusToClosed()
{
    //Get Status ID for the 'Closed Status'

    List<BMCServiceDesk__Status__c> ListStatus = new List <BMCServiceDesk__Status__c>();

    ListStatus = [SELECT Id FROM BMCServiceDesk__Status__c WHERE Name = 'Closed' ];

    List<BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c> listIncident = new List <BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c>();

    //Get all records resolved incidents

    listIncident = [SELECT Id, BMCServiceDesk__Status_ID__c FROM BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c
                    WHERE (BMCServiceDesk__Status_ID__c = 'Resolved'
                    OR BMCServiceDesk__TemplateName__c = 'Incident Resolved')
                    AND BMCServiceDesk__FKRequestDefinition__c = ''
                    AND (BMCServiceDesk__StatusChangeDate__c = LAST_N_DAYS:30
                         OR BMCServiceDesk__StatusChangeDate__c = LAST_N_DAYS:31
                         OR BMCServiceDesk__StatusChangeDate__c = LAST_N_DAYS:32) LIMIT 100];
    for(BMCServiceDesk__Incident__c up: listIncident)
    {
        up.BMCServiceDesk__Status_ID__c = 'Closed';
        listIncident.add(up);
    }
    update listIncident;
}

}
```

Comment: What's the datatype of `BMCServiceDesk__Status_ID__c` field?

Comment: @RCS It's a lookup field, i've edited the post

Comment: I am pretty sure that field is not a lookup. If that field is a lookup, why are you trying to set status strings on it and query it by status strings?